# Reformat iPhone as USB

Tags: iphone, usb

Is it possible to erase and reformat an iPhone to be act as a USB? I've seen many apps that can store data and then you can access it, but is it possible to actually reformat the entire iPhone to behave as a USB?

Comment: To what end, really? 32GB iPhone, 500 quid/bucks/shekels. 32GB USB stick, a fiver.

Comment: Tetsujin it's an old iPhone that I just had lying around, so I was curious if I could use it for this purpose.

Comment: A lot of people turn them into iPods. Drop it in the car glovebox, wire into player, never have to remember again ;-) I did that for years before I got a CarPlay system in the car

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, no.  However, there is an app called [Documents Pro](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/documents-pro-file-pdf-viewer/id374142847?mt=8) ($5 US, and definitely worth it) that would do something similar to what you want.  The difference is that it connects via WiFi as a network drive as opposed to connecting via USB.